# Python simple decorator issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

```
def my_decorator(some_function):
        print("Something is happening before some_function() is called.")
        some_function()
        print("Something is happening after some_function() is called.")

def just_some_function():
    print("Wheee!")

just_some_function = my_decorator(just_some_function)
just_some_function()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I really do not understand, why doesnt this work?

just_some_function should become basically this according to my understanding:

```
just_some_function():
        print("Something is happening before some_function() is called.")  
        print("Wheee!")  
        print("Something is happening after some_function() is called.")
```

But the origional function needs a wrapper function for it to work, e.g.:

```
def my_decorator(some_function):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before some_function() is called.")
        some_function()
        print("Something is happening after some_function() is called.")
    return wrapper
```

Why? Could someone explain the logic behind it please?

Comment: You do realize that this line `just_some_function = my_decorator(just_some_function)` returns `None`. Your function does not return anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorator should create new function that "replace" original function.

```
def my_decorator(some_function):
        print("Something is happening before some_function() is called.")
        some_function()
        print("Something is happening after some_function() is called.")
```

This "decorator" return None -> just_some_function = None -> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

```
def my_decorator(some_function):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before some_function() is called.")
        some_function()
        print("Something is happening after some_function() is called.")
    return wrapper
```

This "decorator" return wrapper -> just_some_function = wrapper -> It's work.

You also can check. Try `print(just_some_function.__name__)` -> "wrapper".

Comment: hmm, interesting. So when I say
just_some_function=my_decorator(just_some_function) 
it means I say, that
just_some_function = the RETURN of the right side, is that correct?

since it doesnt explicitly return something, it will be None?

Comment: Let try again. You say just_some_function=my_decorator(just_some_function) its mean just_some_function = wrapper.

Comment: because wrapper is returned, and NOT because it's the only inner function, is that correct?